# Why can't I programmatically use the Cargo command from within a Child Process?

Tags: javascript, rust, child-process, rust-cargo

I am trying to create something sorta similar to the Rust Playground.

I have coded a rust application that when ran... makes modifications to a project source and calls "**cargo build**" in a certain project's directory and basically programmatically compiles a project for me.

The program I have created works great when I call it directly from the command-line. It compiles the project and does exactly what I wanted it to.

The problem occures when I initiate THIS PROGRAM from within my Javascript code using spawn(). All of sudden, the program panicks at an OS error *"No such file or directory (os error 2)'"*

I have concluded that this is becasue it is unable to find the "cargo" command in it's path... as their is no other file or directory that it could be missing (also, remember, the program works... and calls the **cargo build** command successfully when ran directly from command line)

Here is the javascript code I am using to launch the "compiler" rust microservice.

```
let result = spawn(bin_folder+'compiler',[this.project_dir, worker_id.toString()], { windowsHide: true, shell: true,
                env: { RUST_BACKTRACE: 'true' }  });
```

I am thinking it has something to do with environment variables but I am unable to find the answer with the research I have done.

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING.

Comment: The "no such file or directory" is probably caused by specifying just `"cargo"` and not the full path, as the `PATH` env is not used.

Comment: How exactly are you calling the program from the command line? What environment variables will it have set? With what values are you calling it from your js program? And what is the code of the program, which part does cause the os error?